# Tiempo de respuesta en Query Postgresql

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, sql

Agradeceré ayuda en este caso. No soy experto en Postgresql y hago lo posible.

Tengo una tabla con unos 13000 registros diarios, de ella consulto las columnas fecha (timestamp) y datos (integer) por medio de la query:

```
SELECT 
fecha, datos 
FROM tabla 
WHERE fecha BETWEEN (now() - INTERVAL '1 days') AND now();
```

y su tiempo de respuesta es lento, unos 13 segundos y por lo general la consulta es con un intervalo de 7 o hasta 30 días lo que hace más lenta la respuesta.

La columna fecha tiene un index_fecha Btree: `fecha "pg_catalog"."timestamp_ops" ASC NULLS LAST`

y si hago un Explain Analyze me arroja el siguiente resultado:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on tabla  (cost=15.62..2504.42 rows=701 width=16) (actual time=4.825..8.810 rows=12972 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: ((fecha >= (now() - '1 day'::interval)) AND (fecha <= now()))
  Heap Blocks: exact=158
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on index_fecha  (cost=0.00..15.45 rows=701 width=0) (actual time=4.792..4.793 rows=13407 loops=1)
Index Cond: ((fecha >= (now() - '1 day'::interval)) AND (fecha <= now()))
Planning time: 0.244 ms
Execution time: 10.188 ms
```

La tabla tiene como clave primaria las columnas id y fecha, no tiene claves foraneas.

He probado creando vistas y obtener la info consultando esas vistas pero los tiempos de respuesta no mejoran.

¿Alguna ayuda o idea de como poder mejorar la query o su tiempo de respuesta?  me parecen pocas filas para lo que se demora.

Favor me indican si hace falta más info y cual

Muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Hola. Podrías incluir la sentencia de definición de la tabla y algún dato de prueba para saber qué guardas?

Comment: Hola @Alfabravo, disculpa mi ignorancia, no se sacar la definición de la tabla, pero las características son las siguiente:
Columnas:
  .- id:  int4, length 32, prim.key, not null
  .- fecha: timestamp, length 6, prim key, not null
  .- serial: int4, length 32, not null
  .- evento: text length  0, not null
  .- data: float8, length 53
  .- ttl: varchar, length 10
  .- fecha_epoch: int8, length  64, not null

Datos:
id: 4285906
fecha: 2020-05-18 14:59:56
serial: 1012345
evento: lectura humedad
data: 95
ttl: 60
fecha_epoch: 1589828396

Todos los datos son similares. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Debes quitar las llamadas a la funcion now() de la query. Tal como está ahora, se llama 26000 veces.

Pon current_time en su lugar. Creo que con esto bastará. Si no fuese el caso, entonces ponte el contenido de now() en una variable antes de empezar la query y en ella usas esa variable.

Me lo he vuelto a mirar, y veo que podrías poner simplemente:

```
 SELECT fecha,datos FROM tabla WHERE fecha > current_time - interval'1 day';
```

Todo esto suponiendo que fecha guarde el día y la hora. Eso es lo que se desprende de tu post. Y el resultado contendrá los registros de las últimas 24 horas.

Si fecha es de tipo DATE, y no TIMESTAMP, entonces la consulta podria ser directamente

```
SELECT fecha,datos FROM tabla where fecha >= current_date - 1;
```

Y el resultado será los registros desde ayer a las cero cero horas.

Espero que sirva.

Comment: Gracias @carles, tuve que modificar la query a:

SELECT fecha,datos FROM tabla WHERE fecha > current_timestamp - interval'1 day';

Me arrojaba el error "ERROR:  operator does not exist: timestamp without time zone > time with time zone"

De 13 segundos bajo a 3 segundos y fracción

Comment: Sí, lo supuse. Pero también que el mismo mesaje de error te daría la pista. Me alegro.

Answer (score 0):

Debes agregar un indice a la tabla por el campo que estas filtrando, siempre recomiendo que la tabla tenga organizada la información de acuerdo a como deseas accesarla (where, group by) de lo contrario cuando tengas que realizar algunos join te volverá a ralentizar.
Tu primary key de id + fecha no te da el mismo resultado que un índice.
Y en postgresql, debes cuidar mucho el tipo de datos que almacenas contra los que comparas; fecha por ejemplo tiene diferente formatos: now() es diferente a timestamp y date.